# How do I only allow access to one document for each client using CouchDB (Cloudant)?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I have a JavaScript application which uses a PouchDB instance to store data. I'd like to replicate that data to a Cloudant instance.

Most of the clients using my app and generating the data are anonymous. I'd like to still collect their data without requiring them to log in or sign up. All of the data they generate is stored in a single document. As you can probably tell, this presents a security challenge.

On the one hand, I'd like to permit anyone to read and write to my CouchDB instance, but I only want to give them access to their data. So, if an anonymous user creates a document, I'd like to only allow them to read/write to that document and not others. I don't want them to simply be able to download my entire database.

Reading the Cloudant and CouchDB documentation, it doesn't seem entirely clear how to achieve this. It looks like the following are possibilities:

- Create a new database user each time an anonymous user starts generating data and only give that user access to the document they're going to create.
- Create a new database for each anonymous user and somehow replicate that into the centralized database.
- Figure out how to securely and transparently authenticate anonymous users.

I'm at a loss, probably due to my inexperience with Couch. How would you implement this?

I'm sure the explanation above will need clarification, so please ask away. Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

Comment: why do they need to _read_ from couch?

Comment: The initial document is actually generated server-side, because the server will need to eventually fetch it. The client gets the ID of the doc from the server and then loads it in order to actually start shoving data into it. It needs to read in order to do that, right?